# Which end creates sessions/cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, ruby, session, cookies

Is this correct?

I create cookies using frontend javascript and sessions using backend language (php, ruby etc) ?

If that is true, doesn't creation of sessions mean that the browser has to create a session cookie holding the SID? How can a backend language create a cookie, isn't that only possible with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

php has the setcookie function to set a cookie.

A cookie is merely a small piece of data (name and value) that is sent back and forward upon each request. You can set the cookie on the client using JavaScript, so it is sent back to the server on the next request, but you can set it in PHP also, so it is sent to the browser in the response and is stored there. I believe the sessionid is stored in a cookie as well.

Comment: The sessionid is stored in a cookie if that cookie is a session cookie (created by php and not with javascript) right?

Comment: Yes and no. A cookie is a session cookie (it is automatically destroyed at the end of the session) when it has no expiry date. These cookies can be created using javascript as well. The session id is stored in such a cookie. That is because HTTP is stateless. Every request is brand new to the server. To work around that, cookies can be used to store data in. To prevent every piece of data to be sent back and forth over and over again (including potentially private data), this data is kept on the server, and only a session id is stored in a cookie to identify that data with on the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are created on the server side: when the server responds, it includes a cookie in the http header. The browser passes that back to the server on each request. The server can update the cookie when it wants.

```
Browser ------------------------------> Server
        <---- Set Cookie --------------
        --------- Cookie ------------->
```

Comment: You can [set cookies via Javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)...

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this is correct. You can set cookies with javascript and cookies are client side (stored in the user's browser).

Comment: Yes you can. It is commonly used too.

Comment: Good point, although that's certainly not the common case. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It can be handy when a javascript needs to remember things between page reloads. I've seen this used on a paged list of items. The selected items were remembered in cookies, so JavaScript could show the selected items from the other page. Also, the selection was remembered when going to and returning from another page on the site. I agree it's not the most common use, though.

Comment: Setting cookies in JS is a pretty common phenomenon, particularly with js-based web services. It's also a handy way to give an otherwise static site some user preference settings that will stick between browser sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are attached to the headers of http requests and responses. That makes them accessible to the browser and the server. The only constant in a cookie is the domain it's tied to.

Comment: But when I create a cookie using javascript, then it has nothing to do with the headers right?

Comment: Wrong. A cookie is a cookie. No matter who created it. It is a piece of information that is stored in the browser and sent from the browser to the server on each request. A cookie that is created in PHP is sent to the browser and is stored there. After that response is over, you can't tell if it was PHP or JavaScript that created the cookie.